# Is async await necessary in the following sample code?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm working on an ASP.Net Web API that is used by a mobile application. I'm picking up to where my colleague has left off. I'm just curious about his approach as almost every single function is using async await. Can someone tell me if the `await db.FirstOrDefault<User>(...)` is necessary for the following code? If so, what are the benefits of this?

```
public async Task<Result<User>> GetByUsername(string username)
{
    using (ILoggingContext logger = CreateLogContext("GetByUsername"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new DbContext())
            {
                var record = await db.FirstOrDefault<User>("SELECT * FROM " + DomainName + " where username = '" + username + "'");
                if (record == null)
                {
                    return new LResult<User>("Unable to found " + DataName.ToLower(), logger, username);
                }

                return new LResult<User>(record);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e, username);
            return LResult<User>.DefaultError;
        }
    }
}

public async Task<Result> ResetPassword(string username, string password)
{
    using (var logger = CreateLogContext("ResetPassword"))
    {
        try
        {
            var getProfileRes = await GetProfileByUsername(username);
            if (!getProfileRes.Successful)
            {
                return new Result("Invalid username");
            }
            var profile = getProfileRes.Data;

            var getMembershipRes = await GetMembershipByProfileId(profile.UserId);
            if (!getMembershipRes.Successful)
            {
                logger.Warning("Unable to found membership", profile.UserId);
                return Result.DefaultError;
            }

            var membership = getMembershipRes.Data;
            membership.Password = PasswordHelper.Create(password);
            membership.PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0;
            membership.PasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            return await UpdateMembership(membership);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e);
            return LResult.DefaultError;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/user/resetpassword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody]Login request)
{
    return Ok(await _da.ResetPassword(request.Username,request.Password));
}
```

As far as I understand, the database operation is being executed on a separate thread but we're waiting for it still. And in the code below it, where it's checking for null. What is the difference in just using an ordinary sync method?

Also, I'm really curious at the `return Ok(await...)` part.

Comment: No, the database operation is not necessarily "being executed on a separate thread", and `await` is not "waiting for it still".  Asynchronous programming with async / await is a big subject, it is not something that someone can explain to you real quick in a stackoverflow answer.  Begin reading here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've done some multi-threading in the past but mainly on windows forms, to stop the process from blocking my GUI. What I'm curious is, what's the implication of the async-await in a web api. And thank you for the link :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you read my [intro to async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) article, particularly the first half.

In summary, asynchronous methods work by *freeing up threads*. On the server side, this enables better scalability, since you're using fewer resources to respond to more requests.

In one sense, asynchrony is very similar to parallelism - they are both forms of concurrency (doing more than one thing at a time). In another sense, asynchrony is the opposite of parallelism - asynchrony is about using *fewer* threads, and parallelism is about using *more* threads.